# Assigning nodes (reversing linked list)

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, nodes

I want to write both an iterative and recursive way to reverse a linked list.

Unfortunately, in both cases, I'm running into a similar problem: I am unable to change one node's pointer to a different node, and I'm struggling in some cases with iterating down the list.  For example, here's my recursive reverse function:

```
node *reverse(node *initial){
    node *prev = initial;
    node *nextNode;
    nextNode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    nextNode = initial->next;
    if(nextNode->next == NULL){
        return  prev;
    }
    else{
        nextNode = reverse(nextNode);
        nextNode->next = prev;
    }
}
```

The line `nextNode = initial->next;` crashes the program. I'm sure there's plenty of other issues with this code, and while I'm open to suggestions if its fatally flawed, I mostly just want to resolve this error so that I can debug the rest on my own. In the iterative version, some of the similar lines that crash the program are:

```
startA = startA->next; // startA is a node pointer
backNode = startB; // backNode and startB are both node pointers
backNode->data = frontNode->data; //both ints
frontNode->data = temp; //again both ints
```

By request, the rest of the code:

```
main(){
node *  start = buildList();
int i;
int nodeSize = sizeof(struct node);
reverse(start);
}
```

And buildList:

```
node *buildList(){
node *head = NULL;
node *second = NULL;
node *third = NULL;
node *fourth = NULL;
node *fifth = NULL;

head = (node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
second = (node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
third = (node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
fourth = (node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
fifth = (node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

head->data = 1;
head->next = second;

second->data  =2;
second->next = third;

third->data = 3;
third->next = fourth;

fourth->data =4;
fourth->next = fifth;

fifth->data = 5;
fifth->next = NULL;

return head;    
}
```

Comment: You need to show the calling code of `reverse` function and how the passed parameter is initialized. How are you populating nodes in the linked list that needs to be reversed ?

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `malloc` if you're just reversing the list. Do you want to reverse it in-place, or return a copy?

Comment: You are not returning anything from the `else` statement.

Comment: I was getting an error before that I solved with malloc. I think. That was a solid couple of hours ago though, so I have no idea what my intent was, haha.

Comment: And do I need to have multiple return statements? I just want to change the nodes and return the new head node at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick walkthrough for you:

```
node *reverse(node *initial){

    if (initial is NULL)
        /* this is an empty list so return */
        return a null pointer;

    if (initial->next is NULL)
        /* this is the recursion base case under normal operation - one elem left */
        return initial;

    node *prev = initial;
    node *nextNode = initial->next;

    /* reverse the rest of the list starting at the next node */
    nextNode = reverse(nextNode);

    /* now just reverse the pointers */
    initial->next->next = prev;
    /*
     * but remember that prev->next still points to the wrong node,
     * we need to clear that 
     */
    prev->next = NULL;

    /* you were also missing the return case here */
    /* we want to keep track of the last element (the new head element) */
    /* keep passing this back up through the recursive steps */
    return nextNode;

}
```

Comment: you could probably name the pointers something better to make the code more readable

Comment: Worked. So it wasn't the base case that was going wrong, it was the rest of the recursive function. I'm a little confused though. Why is it initial next next and not just initial next?

Comment: Just write out the steps and you will see. Take the examples of 4 nodes: 1,2,3,4. After the return from the recursive base case, we are at node 3. 3->next->next is the same as 4->next. We want 4->next to be 3, but when we do that we create a circular reference (4->next = 3, 3->next = 4). So set 3->next = NULL and return to the previous recursive step. At the next step, initial is 2, 2->next is 3, and we want 3->next to be 2. So 2->next->next = 2... etc.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Note that when you dereference `nextNode->next` in your `if` statement, you haven't checked for `nextNode == NULL`.

Essentially you're doing:

```
if (initial->next->next == NULL)
```

What happens here if `initial->next == NULL`? This is also an issue with your recursion *base-case*.

Furthermore, your `malloc` is wasted and will cause a memory leak: you assign to `nextNode` a new memory block, then lose the reference to that block when you assign something else to `nextNode` in the very next line: `nextNode = initial->next;` A `malloc` is unnecessary here: you're not adding new nodes to your list, only rearranging the nodes that you have.

When implementing recursion, carefully consider your *base-case*. With your code you want to recurse to traverse your list to its last node, then use `return` to build the list again, backwards. How do you know when you're at the last node in the list? This is your *base-case*, and your recursion function should start there. Can you determine this using only your function argument?

This isn't so different from your current code, but the code you've posted contains a number of mistakes.

Comment: So I tried removing the malloc stuff, while commenting out the line that causes a crash. This caused the program to crash all over again. So even though I'm not sure why, I seem to need the malloc. I'm not entirely sure about the  next->next thing. nextNode is poorly named, I think current might be more accurate. So I don't _think_ I'm going two nodes ahead.

Comment: commenting out the offending line isn't useful: you need to fix it.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to fix it though. Removing the malloc doesn't seem to work, the program still crashes. I really don't see any way that nextNode = initial->next should IMMEDIATELY crash the program (it never reaches any code below that statement). The next several nodes are not null; it should have no issues accessing initial->next.

Comment: And having read your edit, why can't I determine the last node by checking to see if the pointer points to NULL? Isn't that the end of a linked list by definition?

Comment: eventually you will recurse to the end of your list. If your list is constructed properly, you will know this because the last node of the list will have `next == NULL`. Now you're at that point in your function, and `initial` is this last node, so `initial->next == NULL`, and because of `nextNode = initial->next` now `nextNode == NULL` also. What happens when you try to dereference NULL, as with `nextNode->next`? Undefined behavior, in your case, a crash.

Comment: checking that a pointer points to NULL is definitely the way to do it, but your code **doesn't** do that correctly.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying now. So I should change the if statement to     if(nextNode == NULL), right? I tried that, and it still couldn't get past the      nextNode = initial->next line